# How to (highly)compress a file and uncompress on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, compression, zip

i have a few voice files which i am selling with inapp purchase(download with WIFI).
one voice size is approximately 200MB, so my question is:

how can i compress this language files to get not such a big compressed file and can uncompress on iOS?

***Only zipping is not enough. So any other ideas? image? tar? gz?***

*filesize after sipping is 180MB, i want a smaller size if it is possible*

Comment: You'll probably need to consider lossy compression for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to downsample your voice instead. Unzipping in iOS itself is a heavy task for an iPhone App.

Comment: the samplerate is very important for quality of voice in my case. downsampling is not a solution in this case. thanks for your answer.

Comment: @brush51 Quality and small file size usually don't go well together. Your case doesn't seem to be an exception to this.

Comment: If downsample is NOT an option, you can consider streaming it from Internet.